# Handling event of recursively created Mock in Moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm trying to use recursive mocking feature from the **Moq** framework but it doesn't work as I expect it to work.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Moq;

namespace MoqTest
{
    public interface IParent
    {
        IChild Child { get; }
    }

    public interface IChild
    {
        event EventHandler SomethingHappened;
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void RecursiveMockTest()
        {
            // Arrange
            bool isEventHandled = false;

            var parentMock = new Mock<IParent>();
            parentMock.DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock;

            var parent = parentMock.Object;
            parent.Child.SomethingHappened +=
                (sender, args) =>
                {
                    isEventHandled = true;
                };

            // Act
            parentMock.Raise(x => x.Child.SomethingHappened += null, EventArgs.Empty);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(isEventHandled);
        }
    }
}
```

Could please someone explain to me why `SomethingHappened` is never handled? I have an assumption that references of `parent.Child.SomethingHappened` and `x.Child.SomethingHappened` are not equals. If so then why it's not the same?

Comment: I´m using RhinoMocks instead of Moq, so that may be a stupid question, but: Where is the initialization of the Child property of your parentMock object? Do you really get the AssertionFailedException at your last line of code, or is another exception prevailing?

Comment: @Udontknow It's called **recursive mocks** or **auto-mocks**. This line of code `parentMock.DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock;` does the magic. Every time you access some un-mocked property, Moq creates Mock<PropertyType> automatically and returns it. You can find more info on [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all correct, you need the following:

```
[Test]
public void RecursiveMockTest()
{
    // Arrange
    bool isEventHandled = false;

    var parentMock = new Mock<IParent>();
    parentMock.DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock;

    var parent = parentMock.Object;

    // get the actual mock which was automatically setup for you
    var childMock = Mock.Get(parent.Child);

    parent.Child.SomethingHappened +=
        (sender, args) =>
        {
            isEventHandled = true;
        };

    // Act on the mock which was setup for you
    childMock.Raise(x => x.SomethingHappened += null, EventArgs.Empty);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(isEventHandled);
}
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. It works. Thank you very much for help.